# Code not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <style>
            #container{
            width: 520px;
            height:520px;
            border:3px solid black;
            }
            .divs{
            color:white;
            background-color: red;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            float:left;
            border: 2px solid black;
            }
        </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="kalender.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
    $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
   }

  </script> 
 </head>
  <body>
   
   <div id="container">
     
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is not working for some reason, and yes i did add google apis for jQuery. This code worked for my teacher and everyone else my teacher also looked through it and found no problems what so ever.

Comment: Include jQuery library and wrap your code inside Document Ready Event handler or place it at the end of your document just before `</body>`. When this code is being executed, DOM is not yet ready and it doesn't find necessary elements.

Comment: Hats off to the teacher :P

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery. You have to include it https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have missing `jQuery` library please check with this your code working good

```js
for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
  $("#container").append("<div class='divs'>something</div>");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
     
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems:

1. You haven't included jQuery. Add a script tag including it, above the one you have now.
2. Your code is running before the elements it refers to exist. Move your `script` tag to the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag (or use jQuery's `ready` callback, but there's no need here).
3. You haven't declared `i`. While it works, it creates an *implicit global*. Implicit globals are a Bad Thing™. Declare your variables.

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        #container{
           width: 520px;
           height:520px;
           border:3px solid black;
        }
        .divs{
           color:white;
           background-color: red;
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           text-align: center;
           vertical-align: middle;
           float:left;
           border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kalender.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
        }
 });
    </script>   
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you added

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise you code is working

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
  $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 520px;
  height: 520px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.divs {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="kalender.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Jquery in your code in this part.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
        }

    </script>
```

But to use jquery syntax, you need to first include it in your file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your `<head>` tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #container{
           width: 520px;
           height:520px;
           border:3px solid black;
        }
        .divs{
           color:white;
           background-color: red;
           width:100px;
           height:100px;
           text-align: center;
           vertical-align: middle;
           float:left;
           border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kalender.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
        }

    </script>   
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery. And add your script end of the body. Here is my code:

```js
  for (i=1; i<=25; i++) {
    $("#container").append("<div class='divs'></div>");
  }
```

```css
#container{
      width: 520px;
      height:520px;
      border:3px solid black;
    }
    .divs{
      color:white;
      background-color: red;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      float:left;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```